# Maven tests not running when executed from command line

Tags: java, selenium, maven, intellij-idea, automation

I am trying to run one project from the command line using `mvn test` command. It shows build success but not running any tests. I am using TestNG. Console output:

[image]

I have tried all the suggestions provided in StackOverflow but still, it's not running. I don't have surefire plugin as well. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.way2automation.www</groupId>
    <artifactId>SecondMavenTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.uncommons/reportng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- POI JARS STARTS -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- POI JARS ENDS -->


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

[maven cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0vjI.png)

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestNG Suite">


    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="customListeners.CustomListeners"></listener>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"></listener>
    </listeners>


    <test name="BankManagerLogin">
        <classes>
            <class name="testcases.BankManagerLogin" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    
    <test name=" AddCustomerLogin ">
        <classes>
            <class name="testcases.AddCustomerLogin" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    
        <test name=" OpenAccount">
        <classes>
            <class name="testcases.OpenAccount" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    

    
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to configure below plugins in order to run test using maven:

1. Add **[Maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)**: Compiler-plugin is used to compile the sources of our project

   ```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>3.5.1</compilerVersion>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   ```
2. Add **[Maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/)**: Surefire-plugin is responsible for running tests that are placed in test source directory `/src/test/java`.

   ```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
   ```

Both plugin should be under `<plugins>` tag.
Replace your `testng.xml` file relative path here. e.g. A folder name `config` created under your project and placed the testng.xml file, then xml path would be `config/testng.xml`.

Comment: Thank you @NarendraR. For some reason creating a separate folder and moving the testng.xml didn't work. So I kept pom.xml and testng.xml file outside and it worked. The issue was these two plugins were missing. I was with the assumption for Maven 3.6, we don't need the surefire plugin. The same code worked for my friend without surefire plugin so I am wondering what would be the reason. Would appreciate any thoughts. Thanks again for helping

Comment: Glad to hear :)  That was an example in case testng.xml isn't in project root.

Comment: @AVarma It is not a problem with the plugin. It is the problem with the users. This is very natural in all build systems, even in the ANT. There are relative paths considered. It means you run the test from **CWD directory** then the XML is in **CWD/testng.xml**. If the config says **<file>src/test/resources/testng.xml</file>** then the file is at **CWD/src/test/resources/testng.xml** and your POM is at **CWD/pom.xml**. Is it logical explanation? This problem repeats but it is the user error, as the same as the users do not read the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is very natural!

You are in current dir **CWD**, your POM is located in **/pom.xml**, you run **mvn test**, and your configuration says **testng.xml**.

So the topic should be named "Where the testng.xml ought to be".

If the config says **testng.xml** then the Suite XML should be at:

**/testng.xml**

**the same directory where the POM is located - /pom.xml**

But if you configure **src/test/resources/testng.xml**, then the real location of the TestNG Suite XML would be:

**/src/test/resources/testng.xml**, where the **"/"** is the CWD - exactly the directory where the pom.xml is placed and then *src/test/resources* are sub-directories.

Please read the documentation!

Especially see this part in the documentation:

```
      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <file>src/test/resources/testng1.xml</file>
        <file>src/test/resources/testng2.xml</file>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
```

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Running_Tests_in_Parallel